# How to set the scrollbar in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have to create the desktop application for larger screen size. But now I want to put the same application in smaller screen system.

How to set the scrollbar in `JFrame`?

Comment: That's not enough. You need to add more explanation.

Comment: i have to create one desktop application that application works fine in larger screen(1366,748) resolution but now i want to that same application to smaller screen (640,480) resolution. i don't know how to handle my code for the larger to smaller screen..please advise.

Comment: already i use the layout for my screen but now i click smaller screen button the controls and layout are overlap

Comment: *"now i click smaller screen button"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Add the GUI to a [`JScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) before adding the scroll pane to the content-pane.  See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details & working examples.

Comment: Note there are many other possibilities to reduce the size of the GUI, but we would need more details of what is in the GUI and how those controls relate to the work-flow as seen by the user.